# MBP early 2011 EFI update

Tags: efi

I'm trying to install this [EFI Update](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1450). Which is for :

> Mac OS X 10.6.8 / OS X Lion 10.7 and later

And I'm running on 10.9.3 but the update installer throw an alert :

> The update is not supported by your system.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1237) you should use following EFI versions.

```
MacBook Pro (13-inch, Early 2011)   MacBookPro8,1   MBP81.0047.B27 (EFI 2.7)    1.68f99 (SMC 1.6)
MacBook Pro (15-inch, Early 2011)   MacBookPro8,2   MBP81.0047.B27 (EFI 2.7)    1.69f4 (SMC 1.7)
```

Comment: Ok. Then it change the problem. Get ready for a new question ! Here's your +25 :)